# how to disable ligatures for konsole or just when konsole runs vim

Tags: fonts, settings, vim, appearance, konsole

I am using the font https://github.com/belluzj/fantasque-sans

it is a great font and I like it. its just that I cannot turn it off in vim with `let g:tex_conceal = ''`

the problem seems to be that konsole is forcing ligatures konsole-wide

is there anyway to disable ligatures when knosole runs vim or entirely?